# Computing graph efficiency metrics of a very large network

Tags: r, igraph, network-efficiency

#### What are strategies for calculating the nodal and global efficiency of very large graphs in R?

I'm attempting to calculate the global efficiency of a very large `igraph` with `brainGraph::efficiency(my_graph, type = "global")`.

```
library(igraph); library(brainGraph)  
g <- readRDS("path_to_my_graph.rds")  

> ecount(g); vcount(g) # count of edges and vertices
[1] 715758
[1] 290190
```

It reliably crashes R every time. Global efficiency is the mean of all nodal efficiencies, so I've attempted to calculate it that way with no success. The weights on each edge of my graph are all 1, so I've omitted the weights, but R still crashes.

```
# all of these cause R to crash
efficiency(g, type = "global")
efficiency(g, type = "nodal")
efficiency(g, type = "global", weights = NA)
efficiency(g, type = "nodal",  weights = NA)
```

My graph (~37MB) is available [here on GoogleDrive as an .rds file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tw18wcVo9nfclW7SFydOz1MBNpHAxO8-/view?usp=sharing) for those who want data to test.

Comment: Hi @rich-pauloo, I am the author of `brainGraph`. I just noticed the question. As you discovered, the problem is with `igraph::distances`. I can include a check for vertex count and automatically switch to a parallel calculation for a future version. In general, to get my attention, you can open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/cwatson/brainGraph) or join the Google Group (details found in the GitHub `README.md` file).

Comment: Thanks for this comment @ChrisWatson, and thanks for {brainGraph}! It's a really awesome package. I agree that your proposed solution is a great idea. I'll leave an issue on the GH page, a proposed solution, and some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R crashes because `brainGraph::efficiency()` attempts to calculate an enormous and dense distance matrix, which overwhelms the memory of my machine (32 GB). But I found a solution that chunks out the operation and runs in parallel.

Global efficiency is the mean of all nodal efficiencies in the graph. The nodal efficiency of a vertex *i* is:

[image]

We can sequentially calculate the nodal efficiency for each vertex in the graph, which splits the distance matrix calculation into smaller manageable bits. Because the efficiency of each vertex is independent, we can parallelize the operation so it doesn't take forever.

```
library(igraph)  
library(doParallel)

# nodal efficiency function
get_eff <- function(i){return((1/(length(V(g)) - 1))*sum(1/distances(g, V(g)[i])[-i]))}

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1 
cl       <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)  

result <- foreach(i = seq_along(V(g)), .combine = c, .packages = "igraph") %dopar% get_eff(i)

stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)

global_eff <- mean(result)
```

Moreover, we can plot the distribution of nodal efficiencies, as well as the global (mean) efficiency, which gives us a better understanding of the network.

```
library(ggplot2)
data.frame(x = result) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(result), col = "red") # global efficiency
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Nodal efficiences", x = "", y = "Count")
```

[image]